# SQL Server search for number format "ABCABC"

Tags: sql-server

I want to search for number format "abcabc" in SQL Server

Results can be: 324324,567567, ...

I can do it? What is the Solution?

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Are you results always 6 digits?

Comment: So always 6 digits and always consisting solely of a repeated sequence of 3 digits? Would be useful if you showed any edge cases too. E.g. if a number is 1231234 do you want that to be found?

Comment: No, 6 digits at last of number(10 or 11 digits)(example: 01234 324324)

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please [edit] your question to include sample data (including matches and non-matches) and the output you'd like to get from that sample data, along with information about the datatype of the column involved. The sample in your comment makes no sense (`324324` is clear, but I have no idea how `01234` would match `ABCABC`).

Comment: if result always 6 digits, what is the solution? thanks

Comment: what is your column data type that handles the value to be compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @t table (i int)

insert into @t values (123456),(123654),(0),(null)

select i
from @t
where SUBSTRING(cast(i as varchar),1,1)+1=SUBSTRING(CAST(i as varchar),2,1)
        and SUBSTRING(cast(i as varchar),2,1)+1=SUBSTRING(CAST(i as varchar),3,1)
        and SUBSTRING(cast(i as varchar),4,1)+1=SUBSTRING(CAST(i as varchar),5,1)
        and SUBSTRING(cast(i as varchar),5,1)+1=SUBSTRING(CAST(i as varchar),6,1)
```

Comment: @LINH: Does this answer really do what you want? It seems to be solving a different problem.

Comment: I've got the solution based on your idea. Tks so much!

Answer (score 4):

**1. In the simple case** where a value is assumed to be stored as an integer and be in the range of `[100,000; 999,999]`, you can just compare the result of `Value / 1000` (which would be an integral division, because both operands are integral) with the result of `Value % 1000`. The query would look [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25359/1):

```
SELECT Value
FROM dbo.atable
WHERE Value / 1000 = Value % 1000
;
```

**2. If a value** can be larger than 999,999 and you want to determine if its decimal representation contains a sequence of digits matching the `ABCABC` pattern *at any position*, you could first produce a list each item of which is the result of division of the initial value by a power of 10, the power starting from 0 and going on as long as the quotient is equal to or greater than 100,000. To illustrate that by an example, the following list would be produced for the number 123,456,789:

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
```

Next, for each item you would find the result of `Item % 1000000`, which would be a value with the number of digits no more than 6.

Finally, you would apply to the obtained result the test as in the first case, i.e. `Result / 1000 = Result % 1000`. A value for which such a match could be found would be included into the output.

To code all the above in Transact-SQL, I would employ a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) that includes a `0` and use it [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02483/1):

```
SELECT Value
FROM dbo.atable AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Numbers AS n
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.Value / POWER(CAST(10 AS bigint), n.Number)) AS i (Item)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT i.Item % 1000000) AS r (Result)
  WHERE n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND 13  -- 13 is enough to cover the range of a bigint
    AND i.Item >= 100000
    AND r.Result / 1000 = r.Result % 1000
);
```